# How to load html page from side menu to well using div tag and jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

[My Tutorial Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jk0nH.png)

Im doing a simple tutorial page using bootstrap 3. I want to display the html file content on the well container on the right. I dont want to use frame because frame doesnt support most broswer version and Im making this page mobile responsive. I try use frame but it didnt work. I try using src on div tag but it did work either. Other answer only show src link to google.com but how about local hmtl file in folder.

Comment: Can you post a working example?

Comment: We always recommend you to show the code that you have tried where we can find the fault and give you a solution. You are not suppose to ask such question without tried by yourself.

Comment: Its okay. Already asnwered the question

Answer (score 1):

Loading html file render into class name well its simple:

```
   $(".well").load("page.html");
```

Comment: do i need to add anything on div tag? that one line is all needed on the jquery side? How about on the side bar? i also need to href it right? sooo kinda confuse there too

Comment: please, show your code html and javascript and you will receive more complete answer. As i undesrstand, you need add href to tab links and call $(".well").load("page.html"); for each link with href this link

Comment: use iframe supported on most of browsers: <iframe src="./page.html" frameborder="0"> if the html file is in the same directory of your main file: "./page.html'

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>The onclick Event</h1>

<p>The onclick event is used to trigger a function when an element is clicked on.</p>

<p>Click the button to trigger a function that will output "Hello World" in a p element with id="demo".</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incoterm" ></object>';
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```